# Remote IDE on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5

Tags: linux, ide, remote-debugging, redhat, remote-access

I have this version of Linux server:

```
-bash-3.2$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-194.11.1.el5 (mockbuild@hs20-bc2-3.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)) #1 SMP Tue Jul 27 05:45:06 EDT 2010
-bash-3.2$ cat /etc/*release*
cat: /etc/lsb-release.d: Is a directory
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)
```

**Currently, I am writing c program on the Linux side**, I will need the server power to execute my program. **I prefer IDE**, but since **my machine is Windows** and what not, **I have to compile the program remotely on the server**. Sometimes, it's such a pain that I cannot run a stacktrace after the program crashes. And the thing is I want is to achieve higher productivity.

I can only access this server with PuTTY or the like, and **I do not have the rights to install any software.** And **updating the software in the server is also not possible.**

I see that the server got programs like Matlab that can output to XMing on the client side. (Ex. I can run Matlab as a GUI from the server side and have it display on my client device)

I see that some people suggest me for Eclipse, but the IDE is way too slow. In fact, it lowers productivity.

So is there any recommendation or a scheme that will allow me to compile, execute and debug my program remotely on the server with better ease-of-use, given the **bold** criteria above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install as root, but maybe you can manually install applications in your user directory? With that and X11 forwarding you should be set (except a bit of latency).
Also, if you have gdb on the remote (which you probably do since you also have the compiler) you can see stack traces with it after enabling core dumps (ulimit -c unlimited), by opening the binary and the core file: gdb -c  , then bt.